# A large query on the parent component or a series of small queries on each children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, graphql, react-apollo

Hopefully self-explanatory. I'm building a React/Apollo app and I want to ensure I'm using best practice.

Is it better to do a single, large query on the parent app that gets everything the children need (which is then passed via props/state) or just pass the params to the child components and have each child component execute it's own smaller query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends if you need to render all the children at the initialisation of your app.

Example 1:

```
parent -- page A (data 1) -> visible at initialisation
       -- page B (data 2) -> not visible at initialisation
       -- page C (data 3) -> not visible at initialisation
```

In this case, fetch only the data for page A (in page A).

Example 2:

```
parent -- element A (data 1) -> visible at initialisation
       -- element B (data 2) -> visible at initialisation
       -- element C (data 3) -> visible at initialisation
```

In this case, fetch everything (in the parent).

If you need to fetch everything, it's better to have a single large request. Just be sure the backend of your application can handle it properly with good performance. Sometimes it can be better to make a first simple request to start displaying something to your users, and make a second request for something harder to compute in the backend.

Also, a general rule: benchmark your solutions, compare the results and choose the best one.

Comment: Yup. That's what I was expecting. It's a review site for services, most components on the site revolve around a particular service (loaded in via a route) so getting all the service data when the route is loaded and then passing it down the props/state makes the most sense to me, I just wanted to be sure :)